# JQuery Mobile header displayed incorrectly

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've just copied one of my previously created pages (where header is shown normally), removed unneeded content and changed it's id:

[image]

```
<div data-role="page" id="page_web" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">headerheaderheaderheader</div>
    <div data-role="content">
        content
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <div data-role="navbar" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page_home" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page_favorites" data-icon="star">Favorites</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page_settings" data-icon="gear">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

page is called like that:

```
$("#some_button").on("vclick", function ()
    {
        $.mobile.changePage("#page_web");
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header's title should be placed inside `h1` - `h6` tag.

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Omg. I (thought) I've checked that and it doesn't helped. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.

```
   <div data-role="header">
   <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
   <h1>headerheaderheaderheader</h1>
   </div>
```

And check the API : [api.jquerymobile.com/header](http://api.jquerymobile.com/header/)

Comment: back button is generated by jQM `data-add-back-btn="true"` :)

Comment: Nevertheless I +1 you answer because it's also working (contains header tag) =)